# java.nio vs libevent what to chose when working with mass of http requets?

Tags: java, c, nio, libevent

i need to build HTTP server that get requests many of them . like few 10,000-30,000 in 1-5 sec.
its is short/small request.
i need to chose or to go and base it on libevent/libev ( or maybe ACE ?? ) 
or do it in java using java.nio.
i didn't found any benchmarks that compere the 2 like libevent vs java.nio 
or ACE vs java.nio.
what do you experts think?
from my point of view java is more easy to maintain (java is easier then c) 
but i suspect i will pay in performance.
i need advice.
Thanks

Comment: What sort of "http requests" do you need to handle? It's possible that you don't even need a full java server and that something smaller or more targeted would work better.

Comment: Have you checked if grizzly suits your needs? http://grizzly.java.net/

Comment: "suspect i will pay in preference" Do you mean "performance"?

Comment: the requests are json , 200-300 characters long

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).  It's a Java NIO server that's built to handle what you're asking for.

As for benchmarks, the first hit from Google is already four years old:

http://gleamynode.net/articles/2232/

I'd bet that Netty has improved since then.

> from my point of view java is more easy to maintain (java is easier
>   then c) but i suspect i will pay in preference.

I'll assume that you mean "performance", not "preference."  I would say that your suspicion might be incorrect.  Best to get some real data of your own and see.

Comment: thanks i fixed it
the batch mark deals with java nio frameworks,what im asking is 
to do batch mark with libevent based app(c/c++) and  java nio

Comment: Java will probably be slower by about 20% than pure c code. But what you get in terms of maintainability will be huge. The major cause of slowness being data copy from kernel to process memory to java memory while reading and the opposite while writing.